# adding a 3.5 inch screenshot for iOS submission despite Apple dropping support for iPhone 4S

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I finally uploaded my app to iTunes Connect today, and it asked me for a 3.5 inch screenshot.

I didn't develop this app with the iPhone 4S in mind, since Apple dropped support for the 4S on the later versions of iOS. This app has no storyboard that lets it run on a 3.5 inch iPhone 4S.

Do I still have to make the app support the 4S (and submit the corresponding screenshot), despite Apple dropping support for the iPhone 4S?

Comment: What's the deployment target?

Comment: Simply tick the "use 5.5 inch screenshot" for all other categories via the Media Manager in ITC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I just ticked the "use 5.5 inch screenshot" check box and made sure my deployment target was set to iOS 10.0. Looks like Apple doesn't care if my app doesn't run on an iPhone 4S, which is nice.

The app was approved within a day of submission!